# Rails unable to find template for digesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `Rails 5.1.4` with the `mem_cache_store`.

In my controller, I am caching a partial with the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render @objects, cached: true }
end
```

I get the warning below even though that is the correct path to the partial:

```
Couldn't find template for digesting: admin/objects/_object
```

I've tried being explicit:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render partial: 'admin/objects/object', collection: @objects, cached: true }
end
```

But still get the same message:

```
Couldn't find template for digesting: admin/objects/_object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is related to rendering HTML from a JS request. In order to get it to work I have to explicitly name the file with the `.html.erb`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render partial: 'admin/objects/object.html.erb', collection: @objects, cached: true }
end
```